# I can not delete Snapshots (Googleplay services C++ 1.3 SDK)

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games

My code is pretty simple:

```
auto response = Snapshots.FetchAllBlocking();
    if (IsSuccess(response.status))
    {
        for (auto& fetch : response.data)
        {
            Snapshots.Delete(fetch);
        }
```

This throws an exception:
01-27 01:14:11.675: E/GamesNativeSDK(3448): Exception in com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots.delete: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Buffer is closed**..

**What does this mean?**

BTW. in my App and client I have two snapshots, and one of them is super corrupted: I can not open it, always returns ERROR_INTERNAL and IDK what can I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open it with a call to `Snapshots().Open` before calling `Snapshots().Delete`

This is what it means by the buffer being closed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have not tested it (not blocked anymore by this) but makes sense, so I will accept it.